# MS Excel not installed after uninstalling Crystal Reports Viewer

Tags: microsoft-excel, crystalreports

I recently tried out the free Crystal Reports Viewer.  I installed it on my work computer, but it didn't load (crashed on the EULA agreement of all places). After uninstalling the viewer, however, MS Excel 2003 does 3 things:

1. "An error occurred initializing the VBA libraries (1004)"
2. "Microsoft Excel has not been installed for the current user"
3. Excel then closes.

Did uninstalling the CR Viewer take some Microsoft DLLs with it? How do I get Excel working again?

Comment: this is probably a question better for superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Yes, it does appear to have done that.
b) Either restore the system or files back, or reinstall Excel.

Nice userID by the way.

Comment: Thanks. IT has been generous enough to remote connect, uninstall and reinstall all of Office. I rebooted and the problem is still there. All this just to see if it could be of use to us...